# It looks like my javascript interrupts my css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on some little web project

1. I use javascript to change the color - it looks fine
2. I use CSS to change the color when mousehove (`:hover`) - it's fine too

but when I put it together it looks like only javascript works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").css("color", "red");
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#text:hover {
color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button>Set the color property of all p elements</button>

<p id="text">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="text">This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should learn more about the "cascade" and "Specificity" in CSS

Comment: you're using same id two times in a html page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because inline styles have more priority over styling via class. When you add style via `JQuery` using `.css()`, the style is applied as inline style. This has more priority over applying via class. Just inspect and you will see that.

What you should do is

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").addClass('custom-class');
  });
```

and write styles as

```
.custom-class{
  color:red;
}
```

I have tested this and is working.

```css
.custom-class {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").addClass('custom-class');
  });
});
</script>
<style>
#text:hover {
color: blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button>Set the color property of all p elements</button>

<p id="text">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="text">This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because JS code will add inline style that has a high priority than the CSS it will be overridden, you could use classes instead like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("p").addClass('red');
      });
      $("p").hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('hover');
      });
    });
  </script>
  <style>
    #text.hover {
      color: blue;
    }
    .red {
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <button>Set the color property of all p elements</button>

  <p id="text">This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p id="text">This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank i very appreciate i didn't expect that my whole day  problem can fix by add !important

Comment: I didn't recommend the use of `!important` at all, since it can create side effects... You're welcome.

Comment: @NatthakanTheplip use !important only if there are no other optons. choose addClass. This answer is also correct